# CMake генерация .sln(Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Есть CMake скрипт для С++ проекта, c таким содержимым:

```
#...

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug_static")
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADERS_FILES})
endif()

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug")
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADERS_FILES})
endif()

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Release_static")
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADERS_FILES})
endif()

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Release")
    add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADERS_FILES})
endif()

#...
```

В зависимости от типа сборки, тип библиотеки разный. При компиляции все работает как и задумано, но при попытке сгенерировать .sln для Visual Studo все идет не так.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
```

CMake запускается без `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` => Все проверки `if` оказываются `FALSE` => нет тагета нет солюшена.

Если задать `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug_static -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
```

то все 4 конфигурации получаться такие же как `Debug_static`.

Вроде как, на этот случай были придуманы [generator-expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7)), но вот именно тип библиотеки ими задать нельзя.

**Вопрос.** Как заставить CMake сгенерировать солюшен эквивалентный приведенному скрипту? Чтобы было 4 конфигурации: 2 static и 2 shared.

Comment: Как Вы себе это представляете? CMake только один раз генерирует результирующий файл и в нём будет только один `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, из такого кода CMake получить корректные 4 цели в SLN никак нельзя. Такие вещи делаются настройкой соответствующих переменных. Посмотрите как сделаны базовые Debug/Release для MSVS в CMake и сделайте по аналогии.

Comment: @ixSci, последнее можно поподробнее. Куда именно смотреть?

Comment: Посмотрите этот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437692/how-to-add-a-custom-build-type-to-cmake-targeting-make), должно быть хорошим стартом. Я ответ написать не могу сейчас, т.к. точного ответа не знаю — надо разбираться, но это должно помочь.

Answer (score 1):

В отличие от генераторов для Makefile, где конфигурация задаётся при вызове генератора (`cmake ... -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=...`), генератор проекта для MSVS является [мультиконфигурационным](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG.html).

Использованные Вами условия [не работают](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG.html) в случае мультиконфигурационных генераторов CMake. К сожалению, использование [условий и проверок](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#conditional-expressions) для выбора между `STATIC` и `SHARED` в [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html) невозможно, поэтому имеет смысл не указывать эти ключевые слова вообще и воспользоваться [`BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html) при генерации проекта. Это, кстати, позволит избавиться от дополнительных конфигураций с суффиксами `_Static`. Вместо четырёх `add_library` остаётся одна строка

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES} ${HEADERS_FILES})
```

Что бы корректно собрать проект, скажем в Debug, конфигурацию следует указывать при вызове сборки, например:

```
cmake --build . --target install --config Debug
```

Comment: Увы, `add_library` поддерживает генераторые выражения только для списка файлов. Такой CMakeLists.txt просто не распарсится

Comment: Да,Вы правы, что-то я забыл про это и так `add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} $<IF:$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:Release>>,SHARED,STATIC>` действительно не работает